# How to force a notification badge counter to be always in center in css

Tags: html, css

I have a notification badge counter that is centered in specific device width and it changes its position when the device width goes bigger. I want to notification counter to be always in the center.
I am using css and my html/css code is the following:

```css
.nav-menu {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: Calibri, Trebuchet, Arial, sans serif;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  background-color: #ffffff;
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: auto;
  height: 56px;
  z-index: 9999;
}

.nav__link {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-grow: 1;
  min-width: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #4D5656;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  transition: background-color 0.1s ease-in-out;
  font-family: Calibri, Trebuchet, Arial, sans serif;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.nav__link:hover {
  background-color: #eeeeee;
}

.nav__link--active {
  background-color: #84B213;
  color: #fff;
}

.nav__icon {
  font-size: 18px;
}

.item-count-contain {
  top: 3px;
  right: 44px;
  position: absolute;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #dc3545;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 12px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav-menu ">
  <a href="#" class="nav__link ">
    <i class="material-icons nav__icon">home</i>
    <span class="nav__text">Home</span>
  </a>

  <a href="#" class="nav__link ">
    <i class="material-icons nav__icon">notifications_active</i>
    <div class="item-count-contain"> 0 </div>
    <span class="nav__text">Notifications</span>
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="nav__link nav__link--active">
    <i class="material-icons nav__icon">camera_enhance</i>
    <span class="nav__text">Add Product</span>
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="nav__link ">
    <i class="material-icons nav__icon">shopping_cart</i>
    <div class="item-count-contain"> 0 </div>
    <span class="nav__text">Cart</span>
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="nav__link ">
    <i class="material-icons nav__icon">manage_accounts</i>
    <span class="nav__text">Account</span>
  </a>

</nav>
```

Here is how it looks like:

[image]

> NB: The navbar is fixed at the bottom of the page for the mobile purpose.

Comment: When width is known and fixed (20px), than it's easy: `left: 50%; margin-left: -10px`

Comment: Better. Use `translateX(-50%)` together with `left:50%` . That would center it regardless of the width

Comment: remove **right: 44px;** from the **.item-count-contain**

Answer (score 1):

You are using `right: 44px` on `item-count-contain` which is a fixed value so it will obviously be not responsive. Add `left: 50%` and `transform: translateX(-50%)` to move it to center horizontally.

In case you want to centralize it vertically as well then apply `top: 50%` and `transform: translateY(-50%)`

Bot centralization can be combined:

```
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
```

```css
.nav-menu {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: Calibri, Trebuchet, Arial, sans serif;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  background-color: #ffffff;
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: auto;
  height: 56px;
  z-index: 9999;
}

.nav__link {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-grow: 1;
  min-width: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #4D5656;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  transition: background-color 0.1s ease-in-out;
  font-family: Calibri, Trebuchet, Arial, sans serif;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.nav__link:hover {
  background-color: #eeeeee;
}

.nav__link--active {
  background-color: #84B213;
  color: #fff;
}

.nav__icon {
  font-size: 18px;
}

.item-count-contain {
  top: 3px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  position: absolute;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #dc3545;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 12px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav-menu ">
  <a href="#" class="nav__link ">
    <i class="material-icons nav__icon">home</i>
    <span class="nav__text">Home</span>
  </a>

  <a href="#" class="nav__link ">
    <i class="material-icons nav__icon">notifications_active</i>
    <div class="item-count-contain"> 0 </div>
    <span class="nav__text">Notifications</span>
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="nav__link nav__link--active">
    <i class="material-icons nav__icon">camera_enhance</i>
    <span class="nav__text">Add Product</span>
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="nav__link ">
    <i class="material-icons nav__icon">shopping_cart</i>
    <div class="item-count-contain"> 0 </div>
    <span class="nav__text">Cart</span>
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="nav__link ">
    <i class="material-icons nav__icon">manage_accounts</i>
    <span class="nav__text">Account</span>
  </a>

</nav>
```